# ¿Como puedo hacer un insert despues de realizar un update en dos tablas diferentes?

Tags: php, javascript, html, base-de-datos

Quiero realizar un insert a una tabla (historial) despues de que un registro en una tabla (preboot) sea actualizado, sin embargo no se como hacer que esto sea posible, la manera en que hago el update en la tabla de preboot es de la siguiente manera.

```html
<?php
 include_once 'conexion2.php';

 if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id=(int) $_GET['id'];

  $buscar_id=$con->prepare('SELECT * FROM preboot WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1');
  $buscar_id->execute(array(
   ':id'=>$id
  ));
  $resultado=$buscar_id->fetch();
 }else{
  header('Location: preboot.php');
 }


 if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
  $fecha_hora=$_POST['fecha_hora'];
  $cajero_id=$_POST['cajero_id'];
  $marca=$_POST['marca'];
  $modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
  $ubicacion=$_POST['ubicacion'];
  $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
  $carga=$_POST['carga'];
  $estado=$_POST['estado'];
  $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];
  $consola_checker=$_POST['consola_checker'];
  $justificacion_fp=$_POST['justificacion_fp'];
  $contador_dias=$_POST['contador_dias'];
  $contador_hrs=$_POST['contador_hrs'];
  $contador_mins=$_POST['contador_mins'];
  $alertas_detonadas=$_POST['alertas_detonadas'];
  $preboot=$_POST['preboot'];
  $fecha_hora_preboot=$_POST['fecha_hora_preboot'];
  $comentario_preboot=$_POST['comentario_preboot'];
  $booteo_asistido=$_POST['booteo_asistido'];
  $fecha_hora_booteo=$_POST['fecha_hora_booteo'];
  $comentario_booteo=$_POST['comentario_booteo'];
  $acl=$_POST['acl'];
  $fecha_hora_acl=$_POST['fecha_hora_acl'];
  $comentario_acl=$_POST['comentario_acl'];
  $torito=$_POST['torito'];

  if(!empty($fecha_hora) && !empty($cajero_id) && !empty($marca) && !empty($modelo) && !empty($ubicacion) && !empty($nombre)
      && !empty($carga) && !empty($estado) && !empty($ciudad) && !empty($consola_checker) && !empty($justificacion_fp)
     && !empty($contador_dias) && !empty($contador_hrs) && !empty($contador_mins) && !empty($alertas_detonadas) && !empty($preboot)
     && !empty($fecha_hora_preboot) && !empty($comentario_preboot) && !empty($booteo_asistido) && !empty($fecha_hora_booteo)
     && !empty($comentario_booteo) && !empty($acl) && !empty($fecha_hora_acl)
     && !empty($comentario_acl) && !empty($torito) ){
   if(!filter_var($modelo,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
    echo "<script> alert('Modelo no valido');</script>";
   }else{
    $consulta_update=$con->prepare(' UPDATE preboot SET
     fecha_hora=:fecha_hora,
     cajero_id=:cajero_id,
     marca=:marca,
     modelo=:modelo,
     ubicacion=:ubicacion,
     nombre=:nombre,
     carga=:carga,
     estado=:estado,
     ciudad=:ciudad,
     consola_checker=:consola_checker,
     justificacion_fp=:justificacion_fp,
     contador_dias=:contador_dias,
     contador_hrs=:contador_hrs,
     contador_mins=:contador_mins,
     alertas_detonadas=:alertas_detonadas,
     preboot=:preboot,
     fecha_hora_preboot=:fecha_hora_preboot,
     comentario_preboot=:comentario_preboot,
     booteo_asistido=:booteo_asistido,
     fecha_hora_booteo=:fecha_hora_booteo,
     comentario_booteo=:comentario_booteo,
     acl=:acl,
     fecha_hora_acl=:fecha_hora_acl,
     comentario_acl=:comentario_acl,
     torito=:torito
     WHERE id=:id;'
    );
    $consulta_update->execute(array(
     ':fecha_hora' =>$fecha_hora,
     ':cajero_id' =>$cajero_id,
     ':marca' =>$marca,
     ':modelo' =>$modelo,
     ':ubicacion' =>$ubicacion,
     ':nombre' =>$nombre,
     ':carga' =>$carga,
     ':estado' =>$estado,
     ':ciudad' =>$ciudad,
     ':consola_checker' =>$consola_checker,
     ':justificacion_fp' =>$justificacion_fp,
     ':contador_dias' =>$contador_dias,
     ':contador_hrs' =>$contador_hrs,
     ':contador_mins' =>$contador_mins,
     ':alertas_detonadas' =>$alertas_detonadas,
     ':preboot' =>$preboot,
     ':fecha_hora_preboot' =>$fecha_hora_preboot,
     ':comentario_preboot' =>$comentario_preboot,
     ':booteo_asistido' =>$booteo_asistido,
     ':fecha_hora_booteo' =>$fecha_hora_booteo,
     ':comentario_booteo' =>$comentario_booteo,
     ':acl' =>$acl,
     ':fecha_hora_acl' =>$fecha_hora_acl,
     ':comentario_acl' =>$comentario_acl,
     ':torito' =>$torito,
     ':id' =>$id
    ));
    header('Location: preboot.php');
   }
  }else{
   echo "<script> alert('Los campos estan vacios');</script>";
  }
 }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Actualizar Cajero Preboot</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilotablausuario.css">
 <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png" type="image/png"/>
</head>
<body>
 <style media="screen">
  label{
  display: block;
  margin: .5em 0 0 0;
    }
 </style>
 <?php
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
  ?>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <h2>Actualizar Cajero</h2>
  <form action="" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Fecha</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -60px;" type="text" name="fecha_hora" placeholder="Fecha y Hora" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['fecha_hora']; ?>" class="input__text">
     <label>Cajero</label>
     <input style="width: 390px; margin-left: -65px;" type="text" name="cajero_id" placeholder="Cajero" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['cajero_id']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Marca</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -65px;" type="text" name="marca" placeholder="Marca" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['marca']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Modelo</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -65px;" type="text" name="modelo" placeholder="Modelo" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['modelo']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Ubicacion</label>
    <input style="width: 355px; margin-left: -71px;" type="text" name="ubicacion" placeholder="Ubicacion" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['ubicacion']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Nombre</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -72px;" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['nombre']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Carga</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -65px;" type="text" name="carga" placeholder="Carga" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['carga']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Estado</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -62px;" type="text" name="estado" placeholder="Estado" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['estado']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Ciudad</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -70px;" type="text" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['ciudad']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Consola</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -70px;" type="text" name="consola_checker" placeholder="Consola" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['consola_checker']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Justificacion</label>
    <input style="width: 330px; margin-left: -65px;" type="text" name="justificacion_fp" placeholder="Justificacion" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['justificacion_fp']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Dias</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -45px;" type="text" name="contador_dias" placeholder="Dias" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['contador_dias']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Horas</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -60px;" type="text" name="contador_hrs" placeholder="Horas" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['contador_hrs']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Minutos</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -70px;" type="text" name="contador_mins" placeholder="Minutos" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['contador_mins']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Alertas</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -70px; border: 2px solid #d32f2f;" type="text" name="alertas_detonadas" placeholder="Alertas" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['alertas_detonadas']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Preboot</label>
    <input style="width: 380px; margin-left: -75px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;height: 38px;" name="preboot" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['preboot']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Fecha Preboot</label>
    <input style="width: 320px; margin-left: -70px;" type="text" name="fecha_hora_preboot" placeholder="Fecha y Hora Preboot" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['fecha_hora_preboot']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Comentario Preboot</label>
    <input style="width: 280px; margin-left: -70px;" type="text" name="comentario_preboot" placeholder="Comentario Preboot" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['comentario_preboot']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Booteo Asistido</label>
    <input style=" width: 315px; margin-left: -70px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; height: 38px;" name="booteo_asistido" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['booteo_asistido']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Fecha Booteo</label>
    <input style="width: 330px; margin-left: -70px;" type="text" name="fecha_hora_booteo" placeholder="Fecha y Hora Booteo" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['fecha_hora_booteo']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Comentario Booteo</label>
    <input style="width: 285px; margin-left: -75px;" type="text" name="comentario_booteo" placeholder="Comentario Booteo" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['comentario_booteo']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">ACL 1.0</label>
    <input style="width: 385px; margin-left: -70px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; height: 38px;" name="acl" placeholder="ALC" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['acl']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Fecha ACL</label>
    <input style="width: 355px; margin-left: -70px;" type="text" name="fecha_hora_acl" placeholder="Fecha ALC" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['fecha_hora_acl']; ?>" class="input__text">
    <label for="">Comentario ACL</label>
    <input style="width: 295px; margin-left: -60px;" type="text" name="comentario_acl" placeholder="Comentario ALC" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['comentario_acl']; ?>" class="input__text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Torito</label>
    <select style="width: 380px; margin-right: 550px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; border: 2px solid #d32f2f; height: 38px;" name="torito" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['torito']; ?>" class="input__text">
     <option value="Sin Registro">Sin Registro</option>
     <option value="Si">Si</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="btn__group">
    <a href="preboot.php" class="btn btn__danger">Cancelar</a>
    <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn__primary">
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y no se como realizar alguna validacion para poder insertar el registro actualizado a la tabla de historial, al hacer click en el boton de guardar de esta pagina donde el registro se actualiza, solo me interesa llevarme los campos de Cajero_ID, Fecha, Usuario, Accion, Comentarios y Consola, si alguein me puede ayudar, incluso si el update se debe de hacer de otra manera.

Comment: Con un trigger en la base de datos.

Comment: Consulta sobre los triggers en MySQL, creo que son la mejor forma de hacer aquello que deseas.

Comment: Que tal, he estado invetigando un poco, me sinceramente aun no entiendo bien esto de los triggers, lo que he hecho en phpMyAdmin es crear este pero no funciona

CREATE TRIGGER insertaHistorial AFTER Update ON preboot
 FOR EACH ROW
 
INSERT INTO historial (`id`,`cajero_id`,`fecha_hora`,`usuario`,`accion`,`comentario_preboot`,`comentario_booteo`,`comentario_acl`,`consola`) 
VALUES (NEW.id , NEW.cajero_id, NEW.fecha_hora , '0' , '0', NEW.comentario_preboot, NEW.comentario_booteo, NEW.comentario_acl, '0' )